# Rolebased menu access in Active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an active admin application where I try to implement role based restrictions on the resources. I have a number of features which are assigned to a role. For example , the feature "create_user" and "assign_task"  is assigned to the role "manager". I have a table for storing feature list, a table for storing the role list and a table for storing the features assigned to roles. The manager role is assigned to  number of users. When a user logs in, based on the features which are assigned to him, i try to hide some meus. eg: `menu if: proc{current_user.can_create_taskr?}, :priority => 6` . The problem I get is whenever I try to refresh the app, the queries are running everytime, which is unlkely. Is there any way to execute these queries only once after the user logs in and use the results elsewhere

Comment: You can create a special column in your database to save this ability or cache it. The cache or database value can be renewed every time when user login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box ActiveAdmin is relatively inefficient in evaluating menu access each time. If you wish you can use [Rails low level caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) but my advice is don't worry about it until you have to. If the SQL is slow be sure to use indexes.